# best practice to store Unlimited/Max value in DB

Tags: c#, sql, vb.net

I have a few scenarios where I need to store an unlimited value (or maximum, whatever you like to call it), which represents no limitation in business.

A few options I considered:

- Make the field Nullable, and Use DB NULL to represent such case. but the problem is I have to check it anywhere I need to do a comparison or display it.
- Use actual Maximum value of the given type (for example, integer, i can use the largest Int32 value), but this need some tweaks at DB level - I have to write a constraint at the field (as I could use fixed length of decimal or Integer DB type) to limit the maximum value, and it could have no meaning to business either.
- Use a predefined big value (that might make sense to the business) to represent it and store it at DB level, again, i have to write a constraint to the db field.

I have used all of them before for different scenarios, and all are not too bad, but you know, it's a pain to handle some specific cases.

My question is a bit broad: what do you guys suggest for this? what good/best practices are available?

Any help/suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: How do you reference this value in your C# code?

Comment: I use this kind of value at two places normally: display and calculation. for display, it should be masked as "Unlimited", for calculation, I use a huge number (if it's DB NULL) or the actual big value (option 2 and 3); and sometimes, it's also used in stored procedures for reporting purposes (thus it's 'Unlimited' text as well)

Comment: It would be better to explicitly handle the case of infinity instead of just making it a large number.  Your code would probably be easier to understand (even though it may be more writing).

Answer (score 1):

I would think that storing it as a separate column, `IsXyzUnlimited`, may be a good alternate practice.

Since it doesn't mean null, it may not be best to represent it as null. As you mentioned, there is also the problem of checking it before you invoke it.

Also, as you mentioned, the other 2 values could have business meaning. If you want the data to be self-revealing about the business, explicitly say "hey business, this thing is unlimited when this box is checked". No magic values.

Comment: nice approach. only problem is I could think of is it could mix with the value at the other field, if someone else did not handle it carefully, for instance, some report may query records that above certain limit, this one with IsUnlimited should be in and the query would be a bit more complex.

Comment: What actual *business* case deals with infinitely large values?

Comment: @PrestonGuillot, example - U.S. National Debt